# How to write formula to get data from two tables linked together by one column in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

## How to write formula to get data from two tables linked together by one column

> Hi ,

I am new to crystal report. I have a problem to create formula :

Let's say :

I have two tables :

### tbl_Details :

**Emp_id**     **Emp_nameEmp_Deptt** 
 
1            Ram              MMM   
 
2            Naresh           NNN   
 
3            kapil            HHH   
 
4            Namita           DDD

### tbl_Mapping :

**Col_1**    **Col_2**    **Emp_Deptt** 
 
ButterSotch ButterScotch    NNN       
 
ButterScotch    Strawberry  DDD       
 
Olive       Starch      MMM       
 
Olive       Olive       HHH

### Note :  In the above tables, Emp_Deptt column is same.

> Now i want to create a formula like as below :

if Mapping.Type1 = Mapping.Type2 then find Emp_Deptt in Details table and get the Emp_name.
for example : 
Butterscotch = Butterscotch then Emp_Deptt is NNN matched with Details table and the Emp_name is Naresh.

if doesn't find any match then nothing to do.

Now, i want to create a formula to get the desired value and print place somewhere in crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make view of the tables first, join the the two tables, tbl_Deetails with tbl_Mapping..

link them with the department ID.. once its done, call that view to the report and use the formula like this

```
if(totext({view.Type1}) == totext({view.Type2})) then
(
  {view.Employee_Name};
)
else
(
//nothing
)
```

Comment: ya!! sure. I have Join both the tables when adding the database tables using the database explorer. And now i think i have found the solution. if(({tbl_mapping.emp_deptt} = {tbl_details.emp_deptt})) then {tbl_details.Emp_deptt} Also let me know if i am wrong...

Comment: you are doing it right now, please add an empty else statement to be on safe side, please mark the question as answered and do not foreget to rate, please let us know if the formula gives you error. and one more thing, remove the tables now and only use the view... hope this helps.

Comment: can i do this without using views.

Comment: yes you can do it without using the views as well, but then the formula will work perfectly only in the details section, if header or footer section it will give you only one result... should work..

Comment: but it will only give you one result, yes you can put it anywhere.. but in details it will work perfectly okay..

Comment: I have checked the same with details section, its working. could u please tell me how do i create a view in crystal report. I also want to know about the workaround using the view. Because i have to do it in group header as it is the requirement.

Comment: you can create views on sql server, and then call the view from database expert of crystal reports!.

Comment: create a view and group them under Department name, do not display the department name in the group header and use a formula to compare the fields, and it shall work then.. hopefully.

Comment: I have applied the formula as you have mentioned after creating views of both the tables. But i am getting problem with this ... In my report i have one main report and a sub-report. When using formula in sub-report.. it is working fine.. but when applying on main report the data is not shown even main report does not show any data... I have linked both the tables using department id as well. Please respond...

Comment: I have applied the formula as mentioned above, but i am getting unexpected result. I don't know why...

I have used the formula as below :

if({view_type_1.col1} = {view_type_2.col1}) then ( {view_type_1.col3} ) else( "Nothing..." )
In my database i have two rows which is to be displayed in details section. But when i am using this formula.. only one row is showing in details section..since i am using the formula in group header only(using view which you have told me). When i remove this formula or use formula without using views .. then two rows are displaying...